# How do I query this SQL table

Tags: sql

I am learning the SQL query and I have student subject table as below

| ID | Subject | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | English | 30/01/2023 |
| One | Science | 28/01/2023 |
| One | Maths | 30/01/2023 |
| One | Maths | 29/01/2023 |
| Two | Maths | 30/01/2023 |
| Two | Maths | 29/01/2023 |
| Three | Maths | 30/01/2023 |
| Four | Science | 30/01/2023 |
| Four | Maths | 30/01/2023 |

Output:

I need to retrieve the IDs which contains only Maths subject as records as below

| ID | Subject | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Two | Maths | 30/01/2023 |
| Two | Maths | 29/01/2023 |
| Three | Maths | 30/01/2023 |

I tried the below but it retrieves the ID 1 and 4 also.

```
select * 
from subject 
where subject in ('Maths')
```

Comment: you can check this tutorial it should help you with the learning https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: I'd recommend a `NOT EXISTS` condition.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this query:

```
select * from subject 
where ID not in (select ID from subject where subject<>'Maths')
```

Comment: This is simpler than using aggregation in the subquery. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT ID, Subject, Date 
FROM subject 
WHERE ID IN 
  (SELECT ID FROM subject 
   GROUP BY ID HAVING 
   count(case when Subject='Maths' then 1 end) = count(*))
```